# Hotplug protection for serial devices

Tags: serial, hot-plug

I'm building a cockpit for home entertainment and have decided on RS485 for communication and, unfortunately RJ45 to carry the power and data to the panels. I have already made a lot of hardware with this connector so I'm stuck with it after realizing its not well suited for hotplugging data and power without any protection.

Is there another way, other than a different connector that i can protect my hardware? I burned two of my custom designed arduinos by hotplugging the cables. I suspect 12V and the data lines were connected first, before the ground, and 12V went through the AVR and RS485 ICs.

Google turns up some ESD ICs and other forms of circuit protection, but I have no idea where to start. I think my main issue is data pins occasionally making contact before GND.

I'm carrying 2x 12V, 2x GND and the two data lines for RS485 (5V) on the network cable.

It would be great if any specific component is recommended, that it is available at JLCPCB because that's where i order my boards from. https://jlcpcb.com/parts

The full project is available here: https://github.com/maciekish/warthogathome/tree/master/PCBs/Slaves/Nano%20SFF%20Slave

[image]

[image]

The RS485 MAX487 is highlighted and the RJ45 port on the left.
[image]

Comment: Can i perhaps use a resettable fuse such as this one? If so, where do i place it? On the data lines? https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Bhfuse-BSMD0603_05012V/C2844464

Comment: Which RS-485 transceiver is that? Usually they handle being hot-plugged to bus just fine. The problem may be the TXD and RXD on the connector (which by the way is not RJ45, it's a 8P8C modular jack).

Comment: @Justme It's MAX487CPA and CSA. I'm not really sure of the problem, any suggestions will help. As i said i cannot change the connector anymore, so maybe a fuse or other kind of protection will help?

Comment: I believe we discussed this before in another thread, suspecting that 12V and the data lines making contact first, making the data lines become the ground return path and frying the 5v chips on their way?

Comment: There are dedicated hotplug controller ICs for distributed systems out there. They wil lrequire a resign of your pcbs - which allows to use a different type of connector as well. On the other hand: You could connect all PCBs GND directly (soldering, screw terminal, whatever) - this will solve the problem, but makes the power connector somewaht useless.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Can you recommend something in particular? Im using 12V supply for 5V logic and a max of 500mA per slave.

Comment: Please see the search: https://www.digikey.de/de/products/filter/energieverwaltung-pmic/hot-swap-controller/718?s=N4IgjCBcoEwOwDYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iDABxgDMADEsYwKwAsAnOyMXOwhgxeVBvG4j6-Oj2JT2MTpJnU4cEAF1iABwAuUEAGVdAJwCWAOwDmIAL7EOEaCDSQseIqQogFdOos0dfUgjU0sbe3AwGAZkFwwcAmIySEowBDhWCWIhODBOYRz2NSYRGD8BdRyEQQQIHOoGOAZqETgYdnZ68AUGLkCQPQNjc2s7OU5qJWdXdySvVJBYjUiYzjo42cTPFLSBoZCASQtdfCt8E3GQAFphGahTAFcd71ZNWw%2BgA You can get parts with a default (C-programmable) deadtime before internal mosfet switchover. This will solve you problem. There is also UVLO/OVLO/OCP/RBP and "what not" detection

Comment: @MaciejSwic https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS4560.pdf seems useable via the timer option (Use a RC-delay network with sufficient dead-time ~10ms maybe?)

Comment: @MaciejSwic Also i know of RJ45 8p8c cables with different "connector" lengths out there. Designed for such applications. You could have a search for them via digikey/mouser/etc. With a little luck your 7/8=GND layout may fit the available products. Or just let them be custom made - not that expensive these days. May be cheaper than a respin of your boards.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I implemented the DS4560 as it was supposed to be available to order at the fab but it turned out to be sold out even at supplier. I want it all to come together in the fab so im thinking maybe i can create something similar myself? Asked separate question about this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/645419/replace-a-ds4560s-hotplug-protection-ic-with-a-custom-circuit?noredirect=1#comment1711693_645419