# Replace a DS4560S hotplug protection IC with a custom circuit

Tags: mosfet, hot-plug

I intended to use a DS4560S for hotplug protection for my custom Arduinos. Unfortunately it turned out my fab house doesn't have them available even at their supplier and it would be a great hassle. My electronics knowledge is limtied, but I'm suspecting i could build something similar with a mosfet, some resistors and capacitors? I need the time delay and slow voltage ramp-up features of the DS4560. How would one go about designing such a circuit please? I'm looking for a ~100ms delay and at least 100ms voltage ramp-up with a 1.5-2A mosfet.

DS4560 datasheet https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS4560.pdf

Comment: Data sheet link required and a diagram of what you propose please.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, updated the question with the datasheet. I can't make a diagram as I don't know how to design this. My Google-fu only suggested that it might be possible to design a delay and voltage ramp using the mentioned components, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this issue by using a different IC providing the same features, or a basic comparator circuit.

The "timeout generator" is the R1-C1 RC-Circuit.
D1 sets the comparison voltage - just any zener diode or some other reference applied to the positiv op-amp/comparator input.

As soon as the voltage accross C1 is greater then the voltage accross D1 the op-amp/comparator output will be driven low - therefore activating the PNP/PMOS (latter has less power loss!)

You could google some common comparator implementations (hysteresis, start-up stability, etc.) and add additional functions (UVLO,OVLO,OCP,Softstart).

[image: Basic Circuit]

Comment: Thanks, but i have a question. Since this is a PNP which is activated when the base is low, won't it start activated as soon as i apply power? That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: As long as the voltage accross D1 rises faster than the one accross C1 and the comparator/opamp does not have an offset voltage and a low enough VCC_min (And a myriad of other if's) the PNP-Resistance will be rather high. But: There are many thing to validate in regard to component tolerance, non ideal behaviour, start-up stability etc. etc....

I would recommend a "buy and be happy" ready-made IC if low volume production is anticipated and especially if time is an issue.