Is it better to use a NTC or a MOSFET to limit inrush current
I need help to design a circuit to limit the inrush current to a simple motor controller for a 36 V, 250 W motor on an ebike.
When turning on the battery to the controller there is a very large inrush current which, over time, kills the battery switch due to sparks.
The battery pack has high discharge rate industrial headway cells, so it can supply a lot of peak current. How can I limit this inrush current effectively without reducing the efficiency of the circuit? Can I use a NTC, or an inductor, to limit the current or should I go for a more complex MOSFET circuit and if so can somebody suggest a diagram for me.
For the NTC, would a 1 Ω NTC help?
The mechanical switches I have, are designed for 20 A constant current, but I suspect that the inrush current is probably in the order of 50-100 A. I've measured the internal resistance of the motor controller when off as being somewhere around 0.3-0.4 Ω, so is a NTC e.g. 1 Ω enough?

Do you have any datasheet, schematic or other documentation over the "switch" which you say is getting killed? Is it a mechanical switch or a MOSFET? I think e-bikes have to be treated much like cars in respect of inrush current - all electronics design has to assume there's a big nasty surge during start-up for example.

A robust reliable inrush limiter, uses a MOSFET. It has the advantage, that the startup current can be set independently from the on-resistance, in contrast to NTC. So you could make it have a startup current even less than the maximum on-current. Circuit here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/645551/237061

Lundin  and Tobalt:    It's a mechanical switch designed for 20A constant current flow.  the inrush current is so large that it erodes (sparkes) the switch terminals which then become either stuck in toggle switches i used previously or in the case of rotary switches simply do no longer connect with 'zero' resistance and eventually fail completely.       Tobalt:  Thanks for the link.  I will investigate.

Here is one crude way to do it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The ICL (NTC-resistor, here 10 Ω cold resistance) is a nice way to limit inrush, but will suffer voltage drop continuously and would be especially noticeable after coasting when the ICL has cooled down so if you floor it, the motor will bog or motor controller restart until ICL is hot again. A relay is used here in parallel to short circuit the ICL once started after a time delay set by R2-C1. You may want to tune the time constant to suit your system.
Obvious limitations:

Availability of 36 V coil relays. I would probably think about using a 24 V one with a 12 V Zener in series.
No real debouncing of the switch/quick restart. Hopefully your motor controller capacitor is already charged so should not matter much.

This is just one way to do it. Search for DC soft start circuit and you will see many different ways to do it.

The industry's solution to this problem is a precharge circuit. I wrote a white paper about it, if you wish to read it.  In short, we first place a 10 Ohm resistor between the battery and the capacitive load (in your case, the motor controller). After the current settles, we turn on a contactor directly between the battery and the load.
Implementing this precharge circuit requires at minimum some delay modules, at best a small controller.
An Inrush Current Limiter (ICL) works for small batteries. It's impractical for an e-bike. Also, it is no help if someone turns the ignition off and on a few times in quick succession.
By the way, you called that "NTC". But that's an adjective, not a noun, and it's a generic description for anything that reduces at higher temperatures. An ICL, conversely, is an actual electrical component.

Davide,  Thanks for the comment.  Greatly appreciated.   I will implement Winny's circuit ☺☺
